# JFrame help - passing value into PaintComponent()

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've been working on a small "game" project for a while now and haven't been able to pass a value into my `paintComponent` method in any way.

Here's my program. I used a `boolean test` parameter, but the `paintComponent` method does not consider `test` to be `true` and not paint the blue square.

How can I fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Class 1 (Swing):

```
package swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class swing {

    private static  draw object = new draw();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RogueLikeLike MVP");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);;
        frame.add(object); 
    }

static class Move implements KeyListener{

public boolean isFocusTraversable ( ) {
return true;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    char c = e.getKeyChar();
    if(c == 's')
        y+=10;
    if(c == 'a')
        x-=10;
    if(c == 'w')
        y-=10;
    if(c == 'd')
        x+=10;

    object.setAlignmentX(x);
    object.setAlignmentY(y);

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}


}
}
```

Class 2 (draw):

```
package swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class draw extends JPanel
{

    boolean test = true;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /*public void passMethod(draw object) {
        int x = (int) object.getAlignmentX();
        int y = (int) object.getAlignmentY();
    }*/

    public void drawing(draw object){
        draw thing = new draw();
        thing.setX(object.getAlignmentX());
        int x = 55;
        repaint();
    }

    private void setX(float alignmentX) {
        setX((int) alignmentX);

    }

    private void setY(float alignmentY) {
        setY((int) alignmentY);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g, boolean test){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        //int x = (int)object.getAlignmentX();
        //int y = (int)object.getAlignmentY();
        if(test==true)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.blue);
            g.fillRect(getX(),getY(),100,100);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: cleanup for clarity & readability

Answer (score 0):

`paintComponent` can be overloaded, but the overloaded version won't be used to paint the `Component`. Actually `paintComponent` isn't called by the user, but by the painting routine. Instead of overloading the method you should consider using a variable for `test` and reading/updating this variable.
Like this:

```
private boolean test = true;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(test){
        //the rest of the code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't.  This isn't how method overriding works.

`paintComponent` is one of the documented methods used by the painting sub system to allow you to plugin custom painting, in order to work it MUST match a very particular method signature, otherwise, how would the API know what to call

Instead, `paintComponent` should paint the current known state of the component, either directly or indirectly.

What this means is, you component should either have a set of properties which the `paintComponent` method can access or some other object (ie a model) which it can use to determine the current state of which to paint.

You could use a delegate approach, which would allow to define a contract (maybe via a `interface`) which `paintComponent` could call, passing the information you need to these delegates, in order for them to perform the required painting.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

*nb:*

- Add the `@Override` annotation above your `paintComponent` method, the compiler will error telling you that their is no matching method which supports your signature
- Call `super.paintComponent` NOT `super.paintComponent"s"`, this would set up a recursive call which would result in a `StackOverflowError`